# How to generate the users activity report in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building the system in **Django rest framework**, in which the admin level user will govern the local users , I need to keep track of lower level users activity, example: s user activity such as adding some post or deleting and so on other lots of activities. Is there any package or any good implementation on how it can be achieved  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `Track Log` of `Admin` activities like :-

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry

logs = LogEntry.objects.all() # You can also filter
for l in logs:
    #access or perform actions
```

**Edit :-**

To access the time of activity or action. You can access it by **action_time**:-

```
logs = LogEntry.objects.all() # You can also filter
    for l in logs:
        actionTime = l.action_time # Changed Here
```

It will show the time of action made by user

Comment: Thanks !! @PrOgRaMmRr, now I also want the page URLs which user is visiting as well can it be obtained without using request.build_absolute_uri

Comment: How can I trace the time of those activities ?

Comment: I am not being able to get the activity of local users , how to do that ?